# Unable to print values

Tags: list, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to print the values in console which belong to different objects (e.g. countries(more than 100 countries)) having almost same XPath and classes as well. I tried with XPath using List but It doesn't give me expected result. I used following code for one country but same values I need to print for other (more than 100) countries too

```
WebElement GDPAndr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/a/span"));

System.out.println(GDPAndr.getText());

WebElement POPT = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span/span/a/span"));

System.out.println(POPT.getText());

WebElement CO2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span[1]"));

System.out.println(CO2.getText());
```

Looking for help! Thanks

Comment: Provide the html code so we can help you further

Answer (score -1):

Use getAttribute("value"); instead of getText();
Like below:

```
WebElement GDPAndr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/a/span"));

System.out.println(GDPAndr.getAttribute("value"));

WebElement POPT = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span/span/a/span"));

System.out.println(POPT.getAttribute("value"));

WebElement CO2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span[1]"));

System.out.println(CO2.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use value on a span.

Comment: @Shiva Krishna Chippa It returns null :(